# How to add size as custom attribute in React?

Tags: reactjs

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html
As per this documentation, we do not need to have a `data-` as a prefix for a custom HTML attribute in JSX to appear in the actual DOM element without warning.

But when I try and use`<div size="hello">my div element</div>` it appears as `<div>my div element</div>` in actual DOM.

When I try `<div Size="hello">my div element</div>` then it appears correctly but it gives a warning.

What is the right way of adding size as a custom property on the HTML attribute?

example codepen [here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gxNVdP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "size" attribute is a valid attribute for other tags but does not exist on the <div> element React strips it. In the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html#data-and-aria-attributes) you referenced, it does state that you can prefix attributes with data-. "Just like before, React lets you pass data- and aria- attributes freely".

For obvious reasons, this is not recommended and should probably only be done if non-react scripts utilize the attribute.

To answer the question, if you have to store data in attributes, the best option is to prefix it with data-.

Comment: `<div xyz="hello">text</div>` works even though xyz as an attribute does not exists on div.

Comment: you're right, what I meant was that since "size" is a valid attribute, used in for example the <img> tag, React strips it for divs. I'll edit my answer to clarify this.

Comment: I think you are right, but still, it seems like a bug, as if I just make it Size it will let it pass through, the problem with the behavior is that for div xyz and size are essentially the same but they are not behaving the same.

Comment: It's likely not a bug, React just tries to validate your DOM but it will still let through non-standard custom attributes, then it will always lower case all attributes.